# Set scrollbar on element to avoid global scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a single page application, and don't want to have a global scrollbar on the page. Instead of that, I want to have a scrollbar on a specific element, like this:
[image]

In other words, I want element 3 to take all the available place, and if its too big, display a scrollbar on this element.

The solution I found is to set a `max-height` on element 3, computed in javascript as follows : `window.height - element1.height - element2.height - element4.height`.

The problem is that this becomes complex when the page contains a lot of elements.

Is there a way to do this in pure CSS?

Comment: you can use overflow scroll for that

Comment: Overflow needs a fixed height to work. My problem is to avoid this height calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do this easily. Need to tell the overall layout to stick to a certain height, achieved here with `height: 100vh` on the body. Then setting with the `flex-shrink: 1` on the div you want to scroll will allow it to collapse and scroll.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.element {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.element1 {
  background: red;
  height: 10vh;
}
.element2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 10vh;
}
.element3 {
  background: yellow;
  flex-shrink: 1; /* this one must shrink to allow an overflow to occur */
  overflow-y: scroll; /* scroll on overflow */
}
.element4 {
  background: green;
  height: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="element element1">ELEMENT 1</div>
  <div class="element element2">ELEMENT 2</div>
  <div class="element element3">
    ELEMENT 3
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris porttitor quis ipsum ac vestibulum. Integer porttitor ornare dui id accumsan. Ut viverra diam ac nibh luctus, sit amet lobortis diam lobortis. Donec aliquam dolor nec eleifend ultricies. Donec commodo, lacus et bibendum scelerisque, dui libero condimentum ante, iaculis consectetur nisl velit ut ligula. Maecenas nec mattis eros. Donec cursus augue eu erat pulvinar, a tempus justo rhoncus.</p>
    <p>Aliquam id vestibulum elit, sit amet facilisis ex. Nulla pellentesque laoreet augue at fringilla. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec imperdiet rhoncus augue quis condimentum. Donec sed neque mi. Maecenas eget sagittis dui. Morbi a finibus leo. Nam id laoreet dui. Pellentesque lectus lorem, ullamcorper vitae convallis vel, finibus ut lacus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam venenatis elit vel metus cursus malesuada nec vel velit. Donec ac placerat ipsum, aliquet gravida tortor. Nulla lobortis commodo pharetra. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
    <p>Pellentesque sed neque vitae risus iaculis commodo. Integer vel posuere tortor. Mauris finibus ornare velit ut bibendum. Nunc a fermentum leo, sit amet sagittis libero. Sed rutrum neque eu turpis scelerisque malesuada. Sed accumsan, massa vitae pharetra eleifend, arcu dui dapibus enim, sed pellentesque quam sem eget augue. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element element4">ELEMENT 4</div>
</body>
```